# Show NUL character in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm attempting to copy/paste `ASCII` characters from a Hex editor into a **Sublime Text 3 Plain Text** document, although `NUL` characters do not show/display and the string is truncated:

**Hexadecimal**:

```
48 65 6C 6C 6F 2C 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21 00 66 6F
6F 62 61 72 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

**ASCII**:

Hello, World!`�`foobar`�������������������������`

<sub>**Sublime Text**: Truncates copied string and does not show `NUL` characters</sub>
[image: Sublime Text 3]
 <sub>**TextMate**: Shows `NUL` via "Show Invisibles"</sub>
[image: TextMate]
I've tried the [suggestion mentioned here](https://tosbourn.com/how-to-turn-on-invisible-characters-in-sublime-text-2/) by adding `"draw_white_space": "all"` to my preferences — still no luck! Is this possible with **Sublime Text 3**?

Answer (score 3):

You're not alone in having this problem - others have posted bug reports about this behaviour: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/393

However it's not consistent:

> Behaviour seems dependent on the file and where the NUL chars exist;

Similar issue here, with the console: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1939

Comment: Wow, glad I'm not alone, however, not glad there seems to be no resolution.